# Do I need to worry about performance impact of calling useHook when its not used?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, react-hooks

Let's say I have a component like this:

```
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack';

const Button = ({ onClick, confirmClickEnabled = false }) => {
    const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar()

    const onLocalClick = (event) => {
        if (confirmClickEnabled) {
            enqueueSnackbar({variant: 'Confirmation', onYes: () => onClick})
        }
        else        
            onClick()
    }

    return <ButtonBase onClick={onLocalClick} >Button</ButtonBase>
}

export default Button;
```

If `confirmClickEnabled` is `false`, do I need to worry about simply calling a hook such as `useSnackbar()` affecting my performance or not?
**Please note** this button is going to be used a lot, for example, if it's used inside a grid that has 10000 rows, it's used 10000 times.

***Some additional info about why I need this that you might like to read:**

I'm creating a fairly complex library that has its own Button, I was thinking of adding the "confirmClickEnabled" feature where if the button is clicked it shows a notification and asks the user if he is sure that he wants to proceed.

A very easy solution for me is simply implanting this feautre inside my Button component and only using it if the `confirmClickEnabled` is true but I'm worried about any possible performance issue that calling the `useSnackbar` which is a hook for another library might have on my Button component*

Answer (score 1):

> do I need to worry about simply calling a hook such as useSnackbar() affecting my performance or not?

That entirely depends on what `useSnackbar` does. [It looks like](https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack/blob/master/src/useSnackbar.ts) all it is is a wrapper for `useContext`, so the execution time is trivial. Listening to a context does potentially mean that if the context value changes the component will need to rerender, but they have correctly [set the context value up](https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack/blob/master/src/SnackbarProvider.tsx#L34) so it does not change.

Rendering 10,000 rows may still cause you performance problems, but if it does it won't be because of `useSnackbar`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I knew that the wrapper won't change but I wasn't sure if I still should be worried about its performance or not.